# Solving $x'-2xt-t=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general and particular solution of:

$$x'-2xt-t=0\\ x(0)=1$$

Separating the variable I got $\frac {dx}{2x+1}=tdt \implies \ln|2x+1|=t^2+c$.

After this I got confused, after exponentiating everything, how do I get rid of the absolute values?

Also, what does "the maximal interval of existence" mean? Aren't all solutions to an ODE defined in the same domain?

Comment: On the right you want $t\,dt$.

Comment: I think it depends on your particular solution. Since $x(0)=1$, it suggests that $2x+1$ is positive.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using separation of variables

$$ \frac{1}{2x+1}dx = t \ dt $$

You can then integrate both sides

And then:

$$ \frac{\ln |2x+1|}{2} = \frac{t^2}{2} + c$$

$$ 2x+1 = e^{t^2+2c} = Ae^{t^2}$$

where $A = e^{2c}$

You can use your initial condition to obtain a value for $c$

$$ c = \frac{\ln 3}{2}$$

$$ 2x+1 = e^{t^2}\cdot e^{\ln 3}= 3 e^{t^2}$$

$$ x= \frac{3}{2}e^{t^2}-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Why not $|2x+1|=...$?

Comment: You don't need the modulus sign here because $2x+1$ is allowed to be negative.

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry I didn't get that.

Comment: The modulus sign in $\ln|2x+1|$ is there because of the $\ln$. By definition of $\log$, $2x+1$ has to be positive. Hence, once you get rid of the $\log$, you don't need the modulus sign there anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You want $\int \frac{dx}{2x+1}=\int t\,dt$, and the next step is $\frac{1}{2}\ln(|2x+1|)=\frac{t^2}{2}+C$. You can simplify to $\ln(|2x+1|)=t^2+D$. Now evaluate $D$, and continue.

**Added:** Without the initial condition, we get $|2x+1|=Ke^{t^2}$. So $2x+1=\pm Ke^{t^2}=Le^{t^2}$ for some constant $L$ that could be negative. Solving for $x$ we get $x=\frac{1}{2}\left(Le^{t^2}-1\right)$.

Comment: I'm suppose to find the general solution first (without taking into consideration the $x(0)=1$ part), is there anyway to get rid of the $|\cdot |$ before evaluating c?

Comment: So I should write the solution as $2x+1=e^{\pm(t^2+D}\iff x=\frac 1 2 (e^{\pm(t^2+D}-1)$, meaning $x$ is multivalued?

Comment: Sorry, minus sign error. We get $|2x+1|=Ke^{t^2}$, so $2x+1=\pm Ke^{t^2}$. And now solve for $x$. But $K$ can be of any sign, so it can be replaced by $L$ and we get a single form.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dx}{2x+1}=tdt$$
$$0.5\log|2x+1|=\frac{t^2}{2}+C$$
usr $x(0)=1$
$$0.5\log|2*1+1|=\frac{0^2}{2}+C$$
$$C=0.5\log |3|=0.5\log 3$$
$$0.5\log|2x+1|=\frac{t^2}{2}+0.5\log 3$$
$$0.5\log|2x+1|-0.5\log 3=\frac{t^2}{2}$$
$$\log|2x+1|-\log 3=t^2$$
$$\frac{2x+1}{3}=e^{t^2}$$